# Does one way ping affects TCP/UDP socket Communication

Tags: sockets, networking, udp

My current scenario is

System A is able to ping System B.
System B is not able to ping System A. [ Due to Network misconfig ]

Socket Testing :

I am running a UDP server code in System B.
Is it possible to send UDP message to System B from System A(UDP client) even though ping(B-->A) is not working.

Thanks 
Balaganesh

Comment: What if you try it?

Comment: If you can't ping it you can't sent to it.

Comment: Hi . Since One side Ping(A->B) is working fine . I tried sending UDP packets from A to B.But not received it .

Comment: Ping uses ICMP, not TCP or UDP. It is certainly possible that a host blocks ICMP and not TCP or UDP, but that is up to the host configuration.